# Framing a sentence for a short meeting

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

"Could we connect for a short meeting?"

Is this sentence correct or could it be phrased in a better way? The intention is to send this message to someone and do a zoom meeting. I feel there is a repetition here Like I am mentioning connect and meeting in the same sentence. While both have a similar meaning

Comment: It's fine, nothing wrong, and 'connect' and 'meeting' are not really repetition.

Comment: Whilst it's fine, no problem, I think I would have said "Can we hold/have a short [Zoom] meeting?"

Comment: @Peter Will using could instead of can be better or more polite? Especially if I am messaging this to someone in the office.

Comment: @nicku I guess it all depends on your relationship to the other party.  If you are the more senior then "can" is probably what you would use, but if you are the junior then  "could"